# Neutrino temperature

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, photons, temperature, neutrinos

I was wondering if anybody knows the relation between the photon temperature $T$ and neutrino temperature $T_{\nu}$? And why this can be written as

$$T_{\nu}=\left(\frac{4}{11}\right)^{1 / 3} T \mathcal{S}^{1 / 3}\left(x=\frac{m_{e} c^{2}}{k_{B} T}\right)$$

$$\mathcal{S}(x)=1+\frac{45}{2 \pi^{4}} \int_{0}^{\infty} y^{2}\left(\sqrt{y^{2}+x^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{3 \sqrt{y^{2}+x^{2}}}\right) \frac{1}{\exp \left(\sqrt{y^{2}+x^{2}}\right)+1} d y$$

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: have you read this ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_neutrino_background#Derivation_of_the_C%CE%BDB_temperature

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will look at it now

Comment: I understand a little more now, but I do not understand where $S^\frac{1}{3}$ comes from. What exactly is $S$?

Answer (score -1):

The ratio of temperatures is discussed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_neutrino_background . The section "Indirect evidence for the CνB" also describes the math for the ratio. Hope this helps you.